# Passing User information when generating a Stripe Standard Account OAuth Link

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to create a Stripe Standard account for some of my users, and I want them to be able to click on the link directly from an email they will get. This presents the issue that I can't keep track of the user in my site's state and therefore when the authorization succeeds and the user is redirected to my site, I don't have a way to relate the authorization and stripe's user id to his user Id in my platform.

I thought of including their ID in the redirection route, but it doesn't seem Stripe allows dynamic links to be approved on the settings required.

[image]

Are there any workarounds to be able to do this without keeping the user's info in my site's state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `state` URL parameter [0] when generating the link that you put in the email:

https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ca_xxxx&scope=read_write&state=my_user_id

That will be returned as a parameter when the user is redirected to your site after authorising. [1]

[0] - https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize

[1] - https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#redirected

Comment: Like a charm.. Thanks!